# VueJs. Is it possible to pass one <slot> througth another?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evgeniy_Miroshnichenko/m4esok3n/)):
I wont to pass `<component-a>` into slot 'two' in the `<component-c>`

**//file #1**

```
<component-b>
    <component-a slot="... ? ..."></component-a>
</component-b>
```

I have problem in the file #2. I don't understand how I can pass `<component-a>` through `<component-b>` to slot='two' in component .

**//file #2** with `<component-b>`

```
<div>
    <components-c>
        // I was thinking to do it this way, 
        // but as I see It doesn't work:
        // <slot name='one' slot='one'></slot>
        // <slot name='two' slot='two'></slot>
    </components-c>
</div>
```

**//file #3**  with `<component-c>`

```
<components-c>
    <div id='one'>
        <slot name="one"></slot>
    </div>
    <div id='two'>
        <slot name="two"></slot>
    </div>
</components-c>
```

Comment: Could you set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? It's a bit hard to follow what you're trying to do. You can bind to the slot name like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/149/).

Comment: @DecadeMoon Ohh... I'm sorry, but I don't now how to setup 'fiddle' file/files settings. I can use them to get simple examples, but i don't now how to work with then if i need something more. I will look your example right now.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do though? Are you trying to dynamically specify which slot something should be rendered within (like my fiddle), or are you trying to dynamically specify a component which should be rendered in a particular slot?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I have changed your file to show my question more clearly. http://jsfiddle.net/Evgeniy_Miroshnichenko/m4esok3n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for a `<slot>` to be the source for another slot (by using the `slot` attribute) in the parent component. To allow this would mean that a single element (i.e. VNode) would need to have more than one `slot` value for the slots that it would be rendered within as you go up the node tree.

This is not allowed:

```
<slot slot="one"></slot>
```

It will work if you wrap your slot in a div first like this:

```
<div slot="one">
  <slot name="one"></slot>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4esok3n/1/) with your updated example.

Comment: I see that your decision was to wrap 'slots' in 'component-b' in 'div' tag. And as I understand, there is no other way to do that.

Comment: At first I was thinking that it is bad Idea to do like this, but as I see now It looks not so bad as I was thinking. My HTML looks fine, extra wrap Did not damage page view and It looks as it was exacted.  As I see I'v reached my purposes and encapsulated code in different components instead to realize all logic in one.